# net-snmp, get/set sent to shell with object name not OID (linux)

Tags: net-snmp

Someone, who used to work here, configured a linux box to send snmpset/get requests using MIB object names instead of OIDs.  snmpget is called in a shell with some familiar switches and then, bam, just the object name.  How is he doing this?  Is there a way to configure snmp in linux so that you can do this?  I am hearing from coworkers that perhaps there is a way to configure netsnmp on your machine to do the conversion from object names to OIDs.

Answer (score 0):

So we figured this out.  In Linux, snmp can be installed on the command line with sudo apt-get install snmp.  The syntax is the same as net-snmp.  With a basic installation, you have to pas OIDs (which are period separated strings of integers) into snmpget/set to get a response.  However, you can [see here](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Using_and_loading_MIBS) everything you need to set up your machine to take in the object names.  You need to add your mib files to a directory and then point snmp.conf to your mibs.